# Failed to resolve the following dependencies for target framework 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1'

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using ASP.NET 5.0 and I wanted to run just on the new Core CLR, so I removed `"dnx451": { }` from dependencies in my `project.json` file. I now get the following error when I launch in IIS:

> Failed to resolve the following dependencies for target framework 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1':
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta4
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS 1.0.0-beta4
>      Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener 1.0.0-beta4
>      Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles 1.0.0-beta4

My understanding was that AspNet.Mvc 6 would run on Core CLR? Why then do I have to include `dnx451` as a dependency?

My `project.json` file:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Specifying `dnxcore50` as a dependency in `project.json` is not the same as telling the Solution to target that `dnx`. To fix this I had to modify the solution `global.json` file to use a specific version of the `dnx` (i.e. a specific .Net executable). I also had to change a few `using` statements to use new Core CLR libraries instead of .Net 4.5 libraries. You will get intellisense and error warnings about these.

The `global.json` file can be found under the Solution node. I had to add the sdk version part:

```
{
    "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta4"
    }
}
```

Note that you can also edit this in a GUI:

[image]

Strongly recommend the recently uploaded ASP.NET Introduction and ASP.NET Deep Dive videos from Build 2015 available on [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015?sort=status&direction=asc&term=&tag=asp.net#theSessions).

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when publishing my DNX web app. It turned out it was because I had upgraded from Beta5 to Beta6 but neglected to update my publish powershell script which looks like:

```
$thisFolder = (Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName
$webFolder = "$thisFolder\..\src\Web.UI"
dnu publish $webFolder `
 --out \\uatserver\uatshare ` 
 --configuration DEBUG ` 
 --no-source `
 --runtime dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta5
```

So in the last parameter my publish was still telling it to target beta5 instead of beta6.