# Error when upgrading beta5 to beta6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dnvm

I upgraded from ASP.NET 5 beta5 to beta6 using the instructions shown here: [How to upgrade ASP.NET 5 (vnext) from Beta5 to Beta6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745539/how-to-upgrade-asp-net-5-vnext-from-beta5-to-beta6)

I now get a very odd unexpected application error, what could cause this and how do I fix it?

```
Unexpected application failure. Status code '-2146233079'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Exception: Unexpected application failure. Status code '-2146233079'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[Exception: Unexpected application failure. Status code '-2146233079'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +303

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unexpected application failure. Status code '-2146233079'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9940016
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

Here is my dnvm list:

```
Active Version           Runtime Architecture Location                         Alias  
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------                         -----  
       1.0.0-beta4       clr     x64          C:\Users\rlang_000\.dnx\runtimes        
       1.0.0-beta4       clr     x86          C:\Users\rlang_000\.dnx\runtimes        
       1.0.0-beta4       coreclr x64          C:\Users\rlang_000\.dnx\runtimes        
       1.0.0-beta4       coreclr x86          C:\Users\rlang_000\.dnx\runtimes        
       1.0.0-beta5       clr     x86          C:\Users\rlang_000\.dnx\runtimes        
       1.0.0-beta5       coreclr x64          C:\Users\rlang_000\.dnx\runtimes        
       1.0.0-beta5       coreclr x86          C:\Users\rlang_000\.dnx\runtimes        
  *    1.0.0-beta6       coreclr x86          C:\Users\rlang_000\.dnx\runtimes default
       1.0.0-beta6-12254 clr     x86          C:\Users\rlang_000\.dnx\runtimes        
       1.0.0-beta6-12254 coreclr x86          C:\Users\rlang_000\.dnx\runtimes        
       1.0.0-beta7-12264 clr     x86          C:\Users\rlang_000\.dnx\runtimes
```

Comment: The only way I was able to get this to work was by targeting clr instead of coreclr.

Comment: Did you find the cause not working with coreclr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that one of the libraries I was using was not compatible with coreclr.  This may often be the case with 3rd party libraries so I'll leave this here in case others have a similar issue with this not very helpful message.

You change the targeted DNX version with:

```
dnvm install -r clr 1.0.0-beta6
dnvm use -r clr 1.0.0-beta6
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck filing in issue against the repo. https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting Make sure to include information about your project setup (e.g. project.json file, what code is causing the crash, etc)